# why did Yii2 imagine gives Class 'common\models\Box' not found error

Tags: yii2

I'm new to Yii framework & i'm learning this by doing a simple project. In this project i have used extension called yiisoft/yii2-imagine to reduce the resolution of the image but this gives me unknown error.

**My code to resize the image :**

```
use yii\imagine\Image;

Image::getImagine()
      ->open($thumbnail_path.'/'.$this->video_id.'.jpg')
      ->thumbnail(new Box(500,500))
      ->save();
```

**Error**

```
Class 'common\models\Box' not found
```

How i can fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten to specify what Box class should be used. By default the php is looking for `Box` class in your current namespace, so it's looking for `common\models\Box`.
I guess you are trying to use Imagine's `Imagine\Image\Box` class so you need to add a use statement like this:

```php
use Imagine\Image\Box;
```

The other option is to use the fully qualified class name in your code:

```php
use yii\imagine\Image;

Image::getImagine()
      ->open($thumbnail_path.'/'.$this->video_id.'.jpg')
      ->thumbnail(new \Imagine\Image\Box(500,500))
      ->save();
```